# Запись пользовательского ввода в файл QT

Tags: c++, qt

Открыл недавно QT, хочу накидать форму с двумя полями и кнопкой, при нажатии на которую ввод из форм записывался бы в файл. Саму форму накидал в дизайнере. Не могу разобраться с LineEdit, как передавать значение в файл...

```
    QT       += core gui
    
    greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
    
    TARGET = untitled123
    TEMPLATE = app
    
      DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
    
   deprecated before Qt 6.0.0
    
    
    SOURCES += \
            main.cpp \
            testg.cpp
    
    HEADERS += \
            testg.h
    
    FORMS += \
            testg.ui
```

test.h

```
#ifndef TESTG_H
#define TESTG_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class testG;
}

class testG : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit testG(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~testG();

private:
    Ui::testG *ui;
};

#endif // TESTG_H
```

test.cpp

```
#include "testg.h"
#include "ui_testg.h"

testG::testG(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::testG)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

testG::~testG()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "testg.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    testG w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Записывать буду так

```
QFile file("file.txt");
QString str = "This is a test";
if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
{
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream << str.toUpper(); //Запишет-THIS IS A TEST
    file.close();
    if (stream.status() != QTextStream::Ok)
    {
        qDebug() << "Ошибка записи файла";
    }
}
```

Однако тут записывается уже готовая строка, как переделать на пользовательский ввод из LineEdit?
Покажите как это делать или быть может есть проект с 2мя формами и кнопкой по которой записывается в файл... Благодарю заранее.

Answer (score 0):

В [QLineEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html) есть метод [QLineEdit::text()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop), таким образом в методе-слоте обработки клика на кнопке делайте так:

```cpp
void testG::onButtonClicked() {
    //...

    // Получаем текст из QLineEdit в момент нажатия на кнопку
    QString str = ui->lineEdit->text(); 

    //...
}
```

и все